# Test to see if a listbox item is selected

Tags: c#

I have a form that loads 3 pre-defined scores in a list box. I want to convert a selected score into a string, and then output that string in a textbox. So far i think i've converted the item to a string, and tried setting it to the textbox but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
private void frmStudentScores_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lstStudents.Items.Clear();
            lstStudents.Items.Add("Joe Smith|93|92|98");
            lstStudents.Items.Add("Mike Jones|56|61|33");
            lstStudents.Items.Add("Rita Jackson|100|89|96");
            lstStudents.SelectedIndex = 0;
            if (this.lstStudents.SelectedIndex >= 0)
            {
                string a = lstStudents.Items.Cast<string>().ToString();
                txtDisplay.Text = a;
            }
            btnUpdate.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: if you set the `SelectedIndex` to 0 (which means the first item is selected) you cant expect it to be `>=0` on the very next line.  Not sure if that is what `doesn't seem to be working`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your question is about Windows Forms, One way to get the selected item is to use code like this:

```
txtDisplay.Text =lstStudents.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

It is common to want to get the selected item that the user has selected, to do this, you need to place the above code in an event to look like this for example:

```
private void lstStudents_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtDisplay.Text = this.lstStudents.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
```

An event can be wired to the control either by code or via the VS IDE, you can't just copy and paste the above code. Ask me if you don't know how to do that.

If you want to grab the first item only, then Plutonix comment above applies. You don't need the IF statement.

Comment: Thanks, that was simpler than what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is the process at load time, why not try just :

```
private void frmStudentScores_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lstStudents.Items.Clear();
            lstStudents.Items.Add("Joe Smith|93|92|98");
            lstStudents.Items.Add("Mike Jones|56|61|33");
            lstStudents.Items.Add("Rita Jackson|100|89|96");
            lstStudents.SelectedIndex = 0;
            txtDisplay.Text = lstStudents.Items[0].ToString();
            btnUpdate.Enabled = false;
```

**EDIT**

then add at the listbox's event `SelectedIndexChanged` :

```
private void lstStudents_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtDisplay.Text = lstStudents.Items[lstStudents.SelectedIndex].ToString();
        }
```

Comment: I want the display textbox's text to change if I select a different item